# "MySQL server has gone away" when running script as cronjob

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a cronjob running a PHP script that fetches a few hundred RSS feeds, parses them, updates a database, and then writes new Atom and RSS feed files.

The script runs fine when I call it in the browser, but when I let crond run it, it mails me the following error:

```
Warning:  mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in /script.php on line 149
```

Here is the relevant section of code from the script:

```
// ...
// the script has now been running for some time,
// fetching feeds, parsing them, and updating the database;
// now we check if the connection to the mysql server is still there,
// and then query the database and write the feed files

if (!isset($mysqli)) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,
                         $db_username,
                         $db_password,
                         $db_name);
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    $mysqli->query("SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE'");
}

$query = "..."; // some SELECT query

if (!($result =  $mysqli->query($query))) {  // this is line 149
    // error message
}

// write the feed files
// ...
```

As you can see, I check, if the connection stands, before I send the query. Apparently, the database server drops the connection between checking it and performing the query. At least that is what I guess.

So, why is this happening, and **what can I do to keep the connection alive** (if that is actually the problem)?

My PHP scripts run on a shared server (Linux with Apache), and I don't have root access to the MySQL server – so none of the related questions answer my problem, since they all recommend to change settings in the database server config files.

Also, if called from the browser, the script is run under a different PHP version (5.6) than when I have crond execute it (5.5). See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674232/where-on-my-server-is-the-php-version-that-serves-web-pages).

---

I have tried closing the existing connection and reestablishing it, as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7282808/1322720):

```
$mysqli->close();
if (!isset($mysqli)) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,
                         $db_benutzername,
                         $db_passwort,
                         $db_name);
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    $mysqli->query("SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE'");
}
```

and I have tried to set the execution time limit, as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20066642/1322720):

```
set_time_limit(180);
```

or in Prince Rajput's answer below:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

but none of that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first attempt at a solution (given in my question) is that closing a connection does not unset the variable, so that in

```
$mysqli->close();
if (!isset($mysqli)) {
```

the `if`-condition is always false.

One solution would be to unset the variable after closing the connection:

```
$mysqli->close();
unset($mysqli);
if (!isset($mysqli)) {
```

but a simpler solution is to check the connection instead of the variable:

```
if (!mysql_ping($mysqli)) {
```

(Note that of course we do not close the connection to test if it is open.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the header of  cron job file:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
?>
```

Comment: Actually, after several runs of the cronjob, I found that this does not help. With or without `ignore_user_abort(true)`, and both without a time limit (0) and with a specific time limit (e.g. 300) – sometimes the script finishes, and sometimes it doesn't. Apparently this solution does not have an influence on weither the error occurs or not.